# Apigee Cassandra, how to query property with array of objects?

Tags: cassandra, apigee

Suppose this is my data:

```
{
    "info": [
       {
            "name": "Dr. DRE"
       }
    ]
}
```

How do I query in Cassandra all rows that have "Dr. DRE" as name?

```
select * where ..?
```

I have no idea, and didn't find anything useful on google...

Comment: It depends.  Can you edit your post with the result of `desc tablename`?

Comment: Are you talking about Apigee BaaS (Usergrid), or querying Cassandra directly?

Comment: sorry for the total noob response but i don't know how to run that on apigee... All I see is a shell that only accepts HTTP Verbs and a input where i can run CQL over selected tables, there is no shell qhere i can ran that or at least i didn't find it yet...

Comment: I'm using the Apigee BaaS Usergrid, Right now i'm trying the Apigee UI to test the queries...

Comment: OK - note that while Usergrid (a.k.a. BaaS) *runs* on Cassandra, you cannot make direct Cassandra queries using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we clarified that you're using [usergrid](/questions/tagged/usergrid) and not a native Cassandra instance, this should work for you:

```
where info.name='Dr. DRE'
```

(Note that in Usergrid 1.0, `select *` is implied, but you can include it if you like)

While the use of the `=` in this case may seem a little strange, you can use that to look for values in an array.

Comment: YES! U Rock! Tks very much!

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra 2.1 and above you can index the collection and query the collection using a contains in the where clause.  Read more [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddlIndexColl.html) and [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_query_collection_c.html)

Comment: I'm trying the CONTAIN keyword to filter, but i get 0 rows selected.